# Uncertainty estimation of the appearance-based global localization

Tags: covariance, bayesian, pose-estimation

In order to integrate a place recognition algorithm in a bayesian framework, we have to estimate the uncertainty expressed by a covariance matrix. 
The place recognition algorithm contains a database with geo-tagged images and for a certain query, it returns the best match image `j` and the global coordinates. What is the best way to estimate the uncertainty in the returned image `j`?